# best amazon s3 gem with rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, rightscale

I am adding functionailty to our website so users can upload pictures to our site and I'm going to use amazon s3 for that.
I came across these three gems:

1. aws-sdk (https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby)
2. right_aws (https://github.com/rightscale/right_aws)
3. aws-s3

I read that aws-s3 is not as good as right_aws, and doesn't get update as often. But I can't find anywhere that compares right_aws vs aws-sdk and looks like they are both directly written by amazon.

Also I came across an article that was using paperclip and aws-s3 together, do I need to use paperclip with any of those as well?

any ideas?

Comment: I had a very easy time with carrierwave and fog.  https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave  I thin there is a railscast episode on it too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely use [The official AWS SDK for Ruby](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) ([docs](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/)). Some gems unfortunately depend on fog, which was written before amazon's version came out. I would only use fog if another gem, such as carrierwave, dragged it in.